# Change of variables to "minimize spread"

Tags: clustering

First off, apologies for any vagueness in this question; I'm not 100% sure what I'm looking for, so any help would be great!

I have a data that I expect will fit a function `f(x,y,z)` that can be separated into a form `f(x,y,z) = g(x,y)h(y,z)`.  I also know that in theory, with a change of variables `Z = k z - y`, (where `k` is an unknown constant), I should be able to get `f(x,y,z)=g(x,y)h(Z)`.  Thus, I'd expect if I normalize `f(x,y,z)/g(x,y) = h(Z)` then everything collapses onto a single curve.  The problems is that I don't know what `k` is.

The vague question: is there a statistical method where I could somehow find the value of `k` that "minimizes the spread" of my real data?  And what would that even mean in practice?

Thanks!  Please let me know what other detail I need.

Edit [additional detail on statistical model]: The data are in the form of a 4-column vector, with (x,y,z) and f as individual columns. There are errors in all columns, but the data errors in f are much larger, so before I try running any sort of ODR, I'll start by assuming three error-less independent vectors and one error-full dependent vector. However, I do not have evenly spaced data in x,y, and z.

Comment: Please explain what it means for data to "fit a function."  Could it be your data are 4-vectors and the fourth is given by applying the function to the first three, or would it mean your data are 3-vectors and applying the function to them all yields a constant value, or could it mean something else?  What statistical model do you assume about these data?  In particular, do you need to accommodate variation or errors of measurement in all components or just in one component?

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up.  I _think_ I've answered the questions as an edit in the main post.

Comment: Thank you for adding that information.  Would it be correct, then, to suppose your data consist of 4-tuples $(x_i,y_i,z_i,f_i)$ and that you seek to fit a model of the form $$f_i=g(x_i,y_i)h(kz_i-y_i)+\epsilon_i$$ for unknown (and potentially arbitrary?) functions $g$ and $h,$ unknown constant $k$, and random zero-mean errors $\epsilon_i$? And by "minimize the spread" do you want something like a least-squares solution?

Comment: In its broadest form, yes, $g$ and $h$ would be arbitrary. However, assume I know the form of $g$. Then, by "minimize the spread", I mean that if I plotted a graph of $f_i / g$ as a function of a new variable $Z_i = k z_i - y_i$, I would get a single curve, provided that I'd picked the optimum value of $k$.  If I just plotted $Z_i (z_i)$, I would end up with several self-similar curve families parameterized by the value $y_i$.

Edit: reformatted with TeX, and added clarification

Answer (score 0):

Try maximum likelihood estimation of your k parameter.

When you compute the derivatives of the log likelihood, terms tend to disappear and you *may* get some manageable equations. Study how it is done in, e.g., linear regression. It also tries to minimize the squared errors = variance. That will give you some important tricks, e.g., assuming i.i.d. errors. But of course in your case, the assumption probably is that the errors are only i.i.d. after the transformation, not before...

This depends on your assumptions on f. As long as you allow arbitrarily bad functions (e.g. discontinuous, non-differentiable) you probably can't do much. If f is a pseudo random number generator function, for example...